# How can I keep an instance variable DRY in a controller helper with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, module, dry

I am writing this widget that is to be included with a single page of the site, so I don't see a reason to declare what I am doing in the ApplicationController. However, this new widget does have a fair amount of complexity to it, so I want to keep it separate from the controller that normally handles this page since that controller already has quite the bit of complexity in it. I originally figured in my design I could just make a helper module for the controller and keep most of the widget logic there.

I am trying to write this helper module, but then I realized that there is a particular array I need to be able to initialize from a single location, but multiple methods need access to it and it needs to be insured that it is initialized before any other method makes calls to this array. Is there a way to do something similar to a before_filter in such a module where I can ensure this variable is initialized before use or is there a better overall way of approaching this that is the "Rails way"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a new class and instantiate it in the before_filter or your controller.
Not sure what you want to achieve but an example could be :

```
class MyArrayBuilder
  def initialize(some, param)
    #something
  end

  def get_array
    return my_array
  end
end

class SomethingsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :build_array

  def build_array
    @array = MyArrayBuilder.new(some, param).get_array
  end
end
```

Then you pass the `@array` variable to your helper.

I'm not sure there is a "Rails way" of doing what you want : Rails as a lot of convention but when you start to care a lot about design and DRY, I believe it's better to think in term of good practice for Oriented Object Programming than Rails convention.

Comment: You mean define a class in the same file as the controller or define it somewhere else and then just have the controller do a before filter to initialize it? And if not defined in the controller file (this is kind of where I was getting at with the "Rails way" thing), where should it be defined in the rails root directory?

Comment: If you only need it in the controller, I would define it in the controller file, if you will reuse it somewhere else, I would put it in the `lib` or `app/models` directory. 
There is a common approach which is "only put model linked to a table in the database" in the `models` folder but, for me, this is not the "right" behavior, if you can add a class which is a "first citizen" of your domain object, it should live in models.

Comment: So the weird part about this site is that the models are generated on the fly from service calls, so there isn't any use of ActiveRecord at all. Also the reason why I was thinking of separating the logic from the controller is because this is nowhere near the only widget on that page, and the logic in the controller is becoming quite... well... in need of refactoring, and I was wondering how I should approach that.

Comment: I think you can use something like I said in my answer. You can create new classes so you don't mess up the controller code anymore. If you think you will add more of this kind of classes to build widget, you can eventually add a directory `app/widgets` and put your classes in it. When you encounter this level of complexity, there is no Rails way / convention, it's up to you to define your architecture.

Comment: To understand what I mean by following the good practices for Oriented Object Programming with Rails, you can read [Object On Rails](http://objectsonrails.com/) from Avdi, there is a lot of good stuff in it !

Answer (score 0):

You may in need of a good presenter. Look for it in [ruby toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_presenters).

The presenter is a middle ground between the controller and the view. It can access data, and handle complex logic, which is related to presentation, and not to data manipulation. It can do lot of things clean and simple. Check it out, maybe it is good for your problem.

[Tutorial for draper](http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper).